# The Centre view image was not updated in the MAC platform in Radial Bar series chart

Tags: xaml, charts, maui

In Radial bar series chart in MAUI, I used a image at the Centre of the chart.
Initally i displayed button in my output screen, when user click that button it navigate to Radial bar series XAML page and displayed the radial bar chart with Centre view image.
The Centre view image  was appeared in the windows and Android platform.
When I run this code in MAC platform, initially the Centre view image was not appeared but when I resize the output window the image was appeared.

I attached the XAML code for reference. please suggest a suitable solution for this.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Charts;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Charts"
             xmlns:imageExtention="clr-namespace:SampleBrowser.Maui.Base.Converters;assembly=SampleBrowser.Maui.Base"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadialBarBug"
             x:Class="RadialBarBug.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <Button Text="Navigate to Chart Page" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ChartPage());
    }
}
```

ChartPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Charts;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Charts"
             xmlns:imageExtention="clr-namespace:SampleBrowser.Maui.Base.Converters;assembly=SampleBrowser.Maui.Base"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadialBarBug"
             x:Class="RadialBarBug.ChartPage"
             Title="ChartPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <chart:SfCircularChart x:Name="chart"  >
            <chart:SfCircularChart.Resources>
                <imageExtention:SfImageSourceConverter x:Key="imageConverter"></imageExtention:SfImageSourceConverter>
                <local:CornerRadiusConverter x:Key="innerRadiusConverter" />
                <local:BrushToColorConverter x:Key="brushToColor" />
                <local:IndexToItemSourceConverter x:Key="indexToItemSourceConverter" />
            </chart:SfCircularChart.Resources>

            <chart:SfCircularChart.BindingContext>
                <local:RadialBarSeriesViewModel x:Name="viewModel"/>
            </chart:SfCircularChart.BindingContext>

            <chart:SfCircularChart.Title>
                <Label Text="Percentage of Loan Closure" Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" />
            </chart:SfCircularChart.Title>

            <chart:RadialBarSeries LegendIcon="Circle" ItemsSource="{Binding RadialBarData}" 
                                   x:Name="series" 
                               YBindingPath="Value"  
                                   GapRatio="{OnPlatform WinUI='0.4',Android='0.4',iOS='0.5',MacCatalyst='0.4'}" 
                               CapStyle="BothCurve" XBindingPath="Name" 
                               Radius="1" MaximumValue="100" PaletteBrushes="{Binding CustomPalette}" >
                <chart:RadialBarSeries.CenterView>
                    <Border Stroke="{OnPlatform WinUI='White',Android='White'}" 
                            HeightRequest="{Binding CenterHoleSize}"  
                            WidthRequest="{Binding CenterHoleSize}">
                        <Border.StrokeShape>
                            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="{Binding CenterHoleSize,
                                Converter={StaticResource innerRadiusConverter},
                                Source={x:Reference series}}" />
                        </Border.StrokeShape>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Image">
                                <On Platform="WinUI, MacCatalyst,Android">
                                    <Image HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                           Source="{imageExtention:SfImageResource person.png}" />
                                </On>
                                <On Platform="iOS">
                                    <Image HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                           HeightRequest="140" WidthRequest="140" 
                                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                           Source="{imageExtention:SfImageResource person.png}" />
                                </On>
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Border>
                </chart:RadialBarSeries.CenterView>
            </chart:RadialBarSeries>
 </chart:SfCircularChart>
 </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Output in Windows platform
[Center view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT4Mz.png)

When I run this code in MAC platform, initially the Centre view image was not appeared but when I resize the output window the image was appeared.

I want to displays the center view image when the button was clicked (without resizing the output screen) in MAC

Comment: You're only showing what it looks like (correctly) on Windows, but what does it look like on Mac? You're writing that the image appears when you resize the window. This could mean that the window initially is too small to display the content. Try wrapping the entire content in a ScrollView, just to see whether the problem persists. Side note: The `*AndExpand` layout options are deprecated in MAUI and will be removed in the future.